# Configure output as elasticsearch in logstash

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, logstash, amazon-elasticsearch

I'm working on an elasticsearch project where I want to get data from Amazon s3.for this,I'm using logstash.To configure,

```
output{
   elasticsearch{
      host => 'host_'
      cluster => 'cluster_name'
   }
}
```

is the usual approach.
But,I'm using Amazon elasticsearch service. It has only end-point and Domain ARN. How should I specify host name in this case?

Comment: I have no idea about Amazon ES service, but with regular ES, I'd try using this plugin: https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-output-elasticsearch-ec2 with the configuration settings as thesehttps://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-output-elasticsearch-ec2/blob/master/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/ec2.rb

Comment: What kind of domain access policy have you set up for your Amazon ES service?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the simplest case where your ES cluster on AWS is open to the world, you can have a simple `elasticsearch` output config like this:

**For [Logstash 2.0](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html#plugins-outputs-elasticsearch-hosts):**

```
output {
  elasticsearch{
    hosts => 'search-xxxxxxxxxxxx.us-west-2.es.amazonaws.com:80'
  }  
}
```

- don't forget the port number at the end
- make sure to use the `hosts` setting (not `host`)

**For [Logstash 1.5.x](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/1.5/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html#plugins-outputs-elasticsearch-cluster):**

```
output {
  elasticsearch{
    host => 'search-xxxxxxxxxxxx.us-west-2.es.amazonaws.com'
    port => 80
    protocol => 'http'
  }  
}
```

- the port number is a separate setting named `port`
- make sure to use the `host` setting (not `hosts`), i.e. opposite than with 2.0

Comment: That port 80 setting had me going around in circles! I was trying the usual ES 9200 & 9243!